# problem while adding service worker for pwa angular 7

Tags: angular7, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I'm working on a Angular app where I need to integrate pwa for desktop. My app already consist of push notification with fcm and I found this library Service worker which is used for pwa as well. My application has several modules in it for which there is a corresponding server side module that interact with through the API calls.
**Can I use direct server url in my project in start url in manifest file?**
I tried with my local setup but I got below error
[image]

My project angular.json file structure follows

[image]

Fromm root -> src -> I have

- index.html
- sw-app.js
- sw.js

In sw-app.js

[image]

In sw.js

[image]

In index.html I added

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="sw-app.js"></script>
```

In console of service worker

[image]
In manifest file

[image]

**Why I got bad http response code with 404?.. Please help me out**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we should also load **sw.js** file in **angular.json** file.
This resolved my problem.